# Get all Items from nested mapping in Solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

contract DgramMap is ERC721URIStorage {
    struct TokenDetails {
        string src;
        uint256 sell_price;
        string uniqueId;
    }

    mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => TokenDetails)) public userStructs;

    constructor(address payable _admin) ERC721("Dgram Token", "DT") {
    }

    function add(uint256 _id, address _user) public returns (uint256) {
        TokenDetails memory _tokenDetails = TokenDetails(
            "abc.com",
            12,
            "abcs1234"
        );
        userStructs[_user][_id] =  _tokenDetails;
        return _id;
    } 

    function deleteMap(uint256 _tokenId, address _user) public returns (uint256) {
        delete userStructs[_user][_tokenId];
        return _tokenId;
    } 

    function getItems(address _u) public view returns (TokenDetails memory) {

        // Here I want to return hall TokenDetails[_u]
        return TokenDetails[_u];
    }

}
```

How can I get TokenDetails[_u] hall from GetItems?? I am not able to use length also here. Suggest any alternative way if any.
I want this type of structure [ { keyname: {} }].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a nested mapping, you could nest a storage array inside a mapping as follows:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

contract MappingsC {
    struct Item {
        uint groupId;
        uint itemId;
    }
    
    mapping(uint => Item[]) private items;
    
    function setItem(uint groupId, uint itemId) public {
        items[groupId].push(Item(groupId, itemId));
    }

    function getItem(uint groupId, uint itemId) public view returns (Item memory) {
        return items[groupId][itemId];
    }
    
    function getItems(uint groupId) public view returns (Item[] memory) {
        return items[groupId];
    }
}
```

That way, you could return each item individually by passing in a `groupId` and a `itemId` to `getItem(...)`, and still be able to return an entire nested storage array just by passing in a `groupId` to `getItems(...)`. This works as arrays are iterable, unlike mappings.

Comment: {
 "0": "tuple(string,uint256,uint256,string): 11W,1,1,1W"
}

@sagar how can I get this response in nodejs??